# Which balance strategy to learn from my very imbalanced dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, validation, regression-strategies, unbalanced-classes

I'm using a deep learning approach on a dataset made of ~20 millions of elements, where each element has a TRUE or FALSE label.
This dataset unfortunately is **veeery imbalanced**: I've 98% of falses and only 2% of trues.

My algorithm uses three subsets: **a training set, a validation set and a test set**. All these sets are **independent**.

My algorithm runs this way:

> (1) it trains an artificial neural network model on the trainining set
>
> (2) it applies the trained model to the validation set, and computes its ROC AUC
>
> (3) if the AUC at (2) is < 80%, it selects a new model and comes back to (1). Otherwise it goes to (4)
>
> (4) it applies the trained model on the test set

To make my algorithm able to recognize trues and false, I'm using an **artificially balanced training dataset** made of 50% trues and 50% falses; the same for the **validation set** (50% trues and 50% falses).
On the contrary, the test set contains 98% falses and 2% trues.

**Is this approach correct?**

Do you think I should change the artificial balance of the training set? Do you think I should change the artificial balance of the validation set set?

Answer (score 3):

Any method (classification method or choice of accuracy measure) that requires deleting data is deficient.  Once you develop a well-calibrated probability estimation model you can use a proper accuracy score to judge it.  Also, a semi-proper scoring rule, the $c$-index (concordance probability; AUROC) is completely unaffected by extreme imbalance.  So is the coefficient of discrimination described in Section 10.6 of my [Course Notes](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms).

Answer (score 2):

First, you are quite lucky.
Your dataset is quite imbalanced but you have quite a few records. 
If you have ~400K of minority class sample, your imbalance is relative, not absolute.

As for how to validate your results, see [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/810/should-i-go-for-a-balanced-dataset-or-a-representative-dataset/8628#8628)

As for your approach, note that you train and validate on a balanced dataset and you would like to apply the classifier on the imbalanced dataset. You need a way to adapt the classifier you built on the balanced dataset to you regular dataset.

I like to do this adaptation using a technique based on boosting. You can see the details [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157940/what-balancing-method-can-i-apply-to-a-imbalanced-data-set/180316#180316).